# Cannot connect to gRPC Server in Docker Image

Tags: docker, grpc, grpc-go

I am trying to containerize a gRPC-based system in a Docker image, with the ultimate goal of using in in a kubernetes-based deployment. When running the server and client as standalone files, everything works correctly.
The main function of the server is as follows:

```
func main() {
//Start listening to tcp port, if cannot connect then throw an error

const (
port = ":50051"
)

listen, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
}

//start the new server with grpc
s := grpc.NewServer()
VEIv1_0.RegisterVEIv1_0Server(s, &server{})

// Connnect to cloud service procviders
iotCore = connectToAWSIoT()
log.Println("Connected to AWS")
//mqttCli, topic = connectToGCPIoT()

//log.Println("Connected to GCP")

if err := s.Serve(listen); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
}
```

}

After I transform it into an image, I start the containerwith `docker run -d -rm --name windows-server -p 50051:50051 windows-server`. According to the logs, it is running as expected.
When I try to connect to the container with a different program using

```
def main():
frameNum = 0
host = '172.17.0.4'
#According to docker container inspect, this is the IP of the Container
server_port = 50051

#instantiate a channel
channel = grpc.insecure_channel(
        '{}:{}'.format(host, server_port)
)
```

I receive the following error

```
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:172.17.0.4:50051: tcp handshaker shutdown"
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:172.17.0.4:50051: tcp handshaker shutdown {grpc_status:14, created_time:"}"
```

I have also tried to use the gateway IP address and the DNS, also with errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is that there is another error in the server program that is causing it to terminate with an error. When this happens, the container stops. The clients cannot connect to the server container because the server container has stopped.